# PHP's filesize() throws warning stat

Tags: php

I want to print the file size of the songs using the `filesize()` function in PHP. This is my code:

```
<?php
    class parent_class{

        function file_size($filename){
                $size=filesize($filename);
            if( $size>1023 && $size<1048575){
                $size = $size/1024;
                $size = " (". $size." kb)";
            }
            else if(file_exists($filename) && $size>1048575){
                $size = $size/1048576;
                $size = " (". round($size, 2) ." mb)";
            }
            else{
                $size = " (". $size." b)";
            }

            return $size;
            }

        function displaysong(){
             $songs = glob('songs/*.mp3');
            foreach ($songs as $song){ ?>
                <li class="mp3item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $song; ?>"> <?php echo basename($song); echo $this->file_size($song);
                    ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php } 
        } 

         function display_playlists(){
                $playlists = glob('songs/*.txt');
                foreach ($playlists as $file){ ?>
                    <li class="playlistitem">
                        <a href="music.php?playlist=<?php echo basename($file); ?>"> <?php echo basename($file) ; echo $this->file_size($file);?></a>
                    </li>
             <?php } 
         }

         function display_indivsong($file){ ?>
            <li class="mp3item">
                <?php $path = "songs/$file";?>
                <a href="<?php echo $path?>"> <?php echo $file; echo $this->file_size($path);?></a>
            </li>

         <?php }
        
} ?>

<body>
    
    <div id="header">

        <h1>190M Music Playlist Viewer</h1>
        <h2>Search Through Your Playlists and Music</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div id="listarea">
    <?php $song = NULL?>
        <form method="$_REQUEST" >
            <ul id="musiclist" name="playlist">                   
            <?php
            $song = new parent_class();
            if(!empty($_REQUEST["playlist"])){
                $playlist = $_REQUEST["playlist"];
                $path = pathinfo($playlist, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            }
            
            if(empty($playlist)){
                $song->displaysong();
                $song->display_playlists();
            } 
            else if(!empty($playlist) && $path == "txt"){
                $list = $playlist;
                $content = file("songs/$list");
                    foreach($content as $indiv_song){
                        $song->display_indivsong($indiv_song);
                    } 
            } 
            ?>
```

Everything works alright when I display the songs and their sizes. However, when `display_indivsong()` is called, `filesize()` throws an error. Note, inside `display_indivsong()`, the file is used again and it throws an error. But for the first time it is used in the same file, the sizes of the files are returned with no problems.

Comment: "throws an error" **What** error?

Comment: $playlist is the variable that holds the value for the parameter. There is no local path for songs/$playlist

Comment: The error is the error is the same "Search Through Your Playlists and Music Back Hello.mp3 Warning: filesize(): stat failed for songs/Hello.mp3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\New Folder\music.php on line 16 ( b) @ceejayoz

Comment: No one cares about the size of the mp3.  Maybe they might care about the length (min:sec) but even that's doubtful.  Is this a WordPress plugin?  Stop switching between HTML and PHP mode.  There is no legitimate reason to do that.  There are legitimate reason not to do that.  I have a mp3 app I wrote 10+ years ago.  Got a link to your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `display_indivsong()` you are appending "songs/" to the filename before calling `$this->file_size($path)`. Instead of passing `$path`, you should instead pass the original `$file`:

```
function display_indivsong($file){ ?>
  <li class="mp3item">
  <?php $path = "songs/$file";?>
    <a href="<?php echo $path?>"> <?php echo $file; echo $this->file_size($file);?></a>
  </li>
<?php
}
```

This is because the argument passed to `$file` already contains the path.

Also, you're reading filenames from a textfile and then looping through those filenames:

```
$content = file("songs/$list");
foreach($content as $indiv_song){
  $song->display_indivsong($indiv_song);
}
```

This will cause problems if you don't trim the trailing EOL. You should change that line to:

```
  $song->display_indivsong(trim($indiv_song));
```

Comment: the error is the same "Search Through Your Playlists and Music

    Back
    Hello.mp3
    Warning: filesize(): stat failed for songs/Hello.mp3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\New Folder\music.php on line 16
    ( b) "

Comment: The last row of song to display the size has no problem at all. But the files prior to it have error

Comment: @kmoser Why does your code switch between HTML mode and PHP mode?  You should know better than that.

Comment: @Misunderstood It's not my code, it's OP's code, with one change that I made.

Comment: @kmoser The problem with that approach is the OP may get a misconception that it's okay to do that. It's just so Word Press.  Pet Peeve of mine.

Comment: @Misunderstood what would you recommend instead?

Comment: @kim2002 See my updated answer. The problem is that you're failing to trim the trailing newline character at the end of the filename.

Comment: @Misunderstood There is nothing wrong with doing that, despite your misgivings about it. Also, this has nothing to do with WordPress.